# Which Residential Electric Load multiplier is valid for water heaters and EV charging?

Tags: electrical, tankless, electric-vehicle

I know how to perform a residential load calculation using either:
-(a) the Standard Method, which includes a 0.75 multiplier for fixed appliances (so, a 4500W water heater would be treated as adding 3375W to the residence's demand), or
-(b) the Optional Method, which includes a 0.4 multiplier.

Which multiplier should be used with electric *tankless* water heaters or EV chargers? The I've read that some AHJs require including 100% of the nameplate wattage. One Mike Holt thread reported an AHJ treating these things as continuous loads, with a 125% multiplier. Others have arbitrary additors (in one CA county, you just add 15k... regardless of nameplate wattage!). My nearby AHJs have shrugged.

Stiebel Eltron's electrical dept said: "A tankless load is no different than any other load. It falls into the 10k+40% category. It’s used very very occasionally."

Is there an NEC code section on point, or a general rule here? The choice makes extreme differences in load calculations. Thanks!

Comment: These are two extremely different items. A tankless water heater has unpredictable, any time, full load every time, but generally (unless you have a hot water leak) won't run for more than several minutes at a time. An EV charger can be manually controlled - when, how much, etc. but is definitely a continuous load because typical usage is for several hours. Jurisdiction *might* make a difference, so include that.

Comment: Tankless don't need to be treated as a continuous load, but EVs absolutely do.  Note that most people *grossly oversize their EV charging* because of ignorance and "folk knowledge" circulating among novice EVers. 4KW (80% of 20A@240V) is perfectly adequate, and 5.7KW (80% of 30A@240V) is *plenn-teee*.  https://youtu.be/Iyp_X3mwE1w?t=1975 cued to 32:55. See also 28:10 and 25:13.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica is on point there. Also plenty of people go 40A because the 14-50 has become a default outlet for EVSEs. High amp charging really is a niche case.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is most cars are sold with a free *travel* charger. Which has the 2 sockets found *during travel*: the normal one + the one at RV parks. People assume those are their only options.

Comment: See also https://www.diychatroom.com/threads/residential-electric-load-which-multiplier-w-tankless-ev-0-75-or-0-4-or.743353/

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me understand the EV thing -- I'm also studying up on NEC 625 now. But the first comment above nails my issue... how do you factor the tankless into the whole house demand calc? 40% feels wrong because, like you said, a tankless has an unpredictable any time full load etc... but it seems like an arbitrary "well, be conservative" thing... like, I could give this 24kW Stiebel an 80% multiplier instead of the 40% I give to the toaster oven, but...